# How to get start & end time of session in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I am working in asp.net c#.

I have one user login page having userid, password fields & Go button.

After login user gives the mcq test & then sign outs by clicking on Logout link present at the corner of page.
Session starts when user clicks on Go button & ends when user clicks on Logout link.

I want Start time & End time of this session which I want to save in a sql database database as LoginTime & LogoutTime in datetime format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no critical logic behind this. You have to save the start time(GETDATE()) when the user click on the Go button and at the logout click event save the session with nothing and save the end time with current time.

Comment: Then just write the requred data to database. What is the problem? You just want to someone to do a job for you? Here you can ask if something went wrong. To get help, please provide some code and tell more about the problem.

Comment: You can insert date in database when user clicks on Go button similarly on logout but your problem might if user closes browser before logout or power fails

Comment: Thanks Veera. I am getting the logic but not getting how to write it. I tried like Session[Start] = DateTime.Now;

Comment: Thanks @Maris for ur "Rude" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

The folowing code is to set to the webforms which handle login connection :

```
/* Function which handle login */

// ...

Session["startTime"] = /* get the current time here */;

/* End function which handle connection */
```

And this one is put on the webform which handle logout :

```
/* Function which handle logout */

Session["endTime"] = /* get the current time here */;

/* Insert your date in your database, and carrying the date format */

Session["startTime"] = "";
Session["endTime"] = "";

/* End Function which handle logout */
```

Answer (score 0):

When user clicks on "GO" button that time you have to store time using GETDATE(), and
after user clicks on "Logout" you have to follow the same as you have done at "Login" time.